# Searching full text using query parameter in nodejs with 3rd party api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, query-string

I am working on a project, there are some need of searching through API using query parameter. We are using nodejs, expressJs and JSON data format as 3rd party [link](http://universities.hipolabs.com/search). Our API looks like this: `http://localhost/university?name=Cairo&order=Asc`

I have written some code but unfortunately result was not correct. You can see below:

```
router.get('', async (req, res) => {
    await axios.get('http://universities.hipolabs.com/search', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }).then(({ data }) => {
        try {
            const { name } = req.query
            if (!name) {
                return res.send({ status: 'success', result: [] })
            }
            let condition = {
                name: { $regex: name, $options: "i" }
            }
            const fullDatea = data.find(condition)

            res.send({
                status: "Success",
                result: fullDatea
            })
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error);
        }

    });
    
})
```

If you have any idea about how to get the JSON data from 3rd party API, use it inside our application and search the name using query parameter please let me know.

Comment: Can't you just use something like `'http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=' + req.query.name` ? Also, [`Array.prototype.find(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) expects a function as the first parameter not an object and `$regex` is not how you use regex in JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please let us know what do you mean by "result was not correct".

Comment: Thanks @VasiliyArtamonov, 
"const fullDatea = data.find(condition)" at this point blue are undefined when I use 

this "http://localhost:3600/search?name=Canada" url and the json data from the 3rd party api

`{
"country": "India",
"domains": [
"upes.ac.in"
],
"web_pages": [
"https://www.upes.ac.in/"
],
"alpha_two_code": "IN",
"name": "University of Petroleum and Energy Studies",
"state-province": "Dehradun"
},`